# distance between solutions of first order ode with decreasing function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F(t,x)$ be a function which is decreasing in $x$ for every fixed $t$.

Let $x_1,x_2$ be two solutions of the equation $\dot{x}=F(t,x)$.

Let $x_s(t)=x_1(t)-x_2(t)$.

**Prove** that $\forall a<b:|x_s(b)|\leq|x_s(a)|$.

I tried to write $x_i(t)=x_i(a)+\int_a^t F(s,x_i(s))ds$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $t>a$. So:

$$x_s(b)=x_s(a)+\int_a^b \big[F(s,x_1(s))-F(s,x_2(s))\big]ds$$

I don't know how to use the decreasing part, it seems that applying absolute value won't help since using the triangle inequality will not give the desired bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $F$ is defined, continuous and *nonincreasing* in the second variable on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

For definiteness, let $x_1(a) > x_2(a)$.  We want to prove that 
$$
x_1(b) - x_2(b) \le x_1(a) - x_2(b)
$$
for any $b > a$ belonging to the intersection of the domains of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Suppose to the contrary that there exist $b > a$ such that
$$
x_1(b) - x_2(b) > x_1(a) - x_2(a).
$$
Let
$$
\theta := \inf\{ t \in [a, b]: x_1(t) - x_2(t) > x_1(a) - x_2(a)\}.
$$
One has $\theta \in [a, b)$, and $x_1(\theta) - x_2(\theta) = x_1(a) - x_2(a)$.  Apply the MVT to $x_1 - x_2$ on $[\theta, b]$ to obtain the existence of $\tau \in (\theta, b)$ such that
$$
(x_1(b) - x_2(b)) - (x_1(\theta) - x_2(\theta)) = (x_1'(\tau) -x_2'(\tau)) \cdot (b - \theta).
$$
The LHS is positive.  But $x_1'(\tau) -x_2'(\tau) = F(\tau, x_1(\tau)) - F(\tau, x_2(\tau)) \le 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why is it enough to prove that $x_1(b)-x_2(b)\leq x_1(a)-x_2(a)$, what about $x_2(b)-x_1(b)\leq x_1(a)-x_2(a)$. I mean since the question requires the absolute value.

Comment: I consider only one case, $x_1(a) - x_2(a) > 0$, that is, $\lvert x_1(a) - x_2(a) \rvert = x_1(a) - x_2(a)$ (because the other one is analogous).  The difference $x_1 - x_2$ is nonincreasing as long as $x_1(t) > x_2(t)$.  If the latter holds for all $t \ge a$, we are done.  If $x_1(T) = x_2(T)$ for  some $T > a$, then the previous reasoning shows that $x_1(t) = x_2(t)$ for all $t \ge T$ (this is sometimes called Peano's uniqueness theorem, see my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706189/studying-mullers-example-of-ivp-with-unique-solution-whose-picard-iterates-do-n).