# Apply the picard iteration to the first-order equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Apply the picard iteration to the first-order equation

$x'=2t-2 \sqrt{max(0,x)} \,\, , x(0)=0 $.

Does it converge?

In this case should we separate in cases"$x>0$ and $x<0$ ", and resolve the ODEs separately, or should we use another strategy?

Comment: We have $\varphi_0(t)=0$,
$$
\varphi_1(t) = \int_0^t 2\left(s-\mathrm{max}\{\sqrt 0,0\}\right)\ \mathsf ds = t^2,
$$
and
$$
\varphi_2(t) = \int_0^t 2\left(s-\mathrm{max}\{\sqrt 0,s^2\}\right)\ \mathsf ds = \int_0^t 2\left(s-\sqrt{s^2}\right)\ \mathsf ds = 0,
$$
so the Picard iterates don't converge.

Comment: The Picard–Lindelöf theorem doesn't apply here since the map $x\mapsto 2(t-\sqrt x)$ is not uniformly Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!