# Picard Theorem problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the EDO : \begin{equation} (P)\left\{ \begin{array}{r l} 
                                    x^{´} & =f(t,x) \\ 
                                    x(0) & = 0 
\end{array}\right. \end{equation}

where  : \begin{equation} f(t,x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 
                                    0 & t \leq 0, x\in \mathbb{R}  \\ 
                                    2t & 0<t<1, x<0 \\
                                    2t-\dfrac{4x}{t} & 0<t<1,0\leq x \leq t^2 \\
                                    -2t & 0<t<1, t^2<x 
\end{array}\right. \end{equation}

$(P)$ has unique solution ? 
if yes, find the iterations of Picard.

$\textbf{My attempt :}$

If I prove that $ f $ is lipschitz with respect to the second variable, I could apply Picard's theorem but I do not know how to work with the definition of $ f $. Any idea?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Studying Muller's example of IVP with unique solution whose Picard iterates do not converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706189/studying-mullers-example-of-ivp-with-unique-solution-whose-picard-iterates-do-n/2706676#2706676).

Answer (score 2):

In the part $0<t<1$, $\>0\leq x\leq t^2$ you have
$${|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_0)|\over |x_1-x_0|}={4\over t}\ .$$The right side here is unbounded in every neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Therefore the basic technical assumption for Picard's theorem is not fulfilled for your IVP.